# LNK2019/ 1120 Error : Armadillo / BLAS LAPACK / VS 2019 / clang

Tags: cmake, dependencies, linker-errors, armadillo, lapack

When I use `cmake` with **VS 2019 (win10)** there is no project properties menu to set the additional dependencies. I think I should do it using `cmake` commands in `cmakelists.txt` file. I can build with `Armadillo` but if `.cpp` includes the `det(A)` command building creates linker error. I think I couldn't link to blas and lapack libs.

I included `Armadillo\armadillo-9.800.1\include` directory.
I also included `Armadillo\armadillo-9.800.1\examples\lib_win64` directory but it is not enough if I understand correctly. I need to know the corresponding command to additional dependencies setting of **VS** in `cmake`.

I get the error: `LNK2019 unresolved external symbol dgetrf referenced in function void __cdecl arma::lapack::getrf<double>(int *,int *,double *,int *,int *,int *)`

cmakelists.txt content is:

```
project(CMakeProject9)

cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

# Add source to this project's executable.
add_executable (CMakeProject9 "CMakeProject9.cpp" "CMakeProject9.h")

# TODO: Add tests and install targets if needed.
target_include_directories(CMakeProject9 PRIVATE "C:/Projects/Armadillo/armadillo-9.800.1/include" "C:/Projects/Armadillo/armadillo-9.800.1/examples/lib_win64")

target_link_libraries(CMakeProject9 PRIVATE "C:/Projects/Armadillo/armadillo-9.800.1/examples/lib_win64")
```

Even if I remove linking commands from the cmakelists.txt file (adding below) I get the same error. They are ineffective. Or I cant use them correctly.

```
project(CMakeProject9)

    cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

    # Add source to this project's executable.
    add_executable (CMakeProject9 "CMakeProject9.cpp" "CMakeProject9.h")

    # TODO: Add tests and install targets if needed.
    target_include_directories(CMakeProject9 PRIVATE "C:/Projects/Armadillo/armadillo-9.800.1/include")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please add the CMake file you are using to your post? We can only **guess** what the problem might be with the little information you've provided.

Comment: How did you install armadillo?
Are you using armadillo as a header only library or are you are you using the wrapper (libarmadillo)?.

Comment: @darcamo I am using header library. Actually it is working well when I comment out #cmakedefine ARMA_USE_LAPACK and #cmakedefine ARMA_USE_BLAS lines of config.hpp. The problem is related with blas and lapack linking I assume. Or related with the lib files I don't understand.